# How to delete file by access time in linux?

Tags: linux, find

I want to delete *.mp3 files that access time is older from 10 minutes in a directory. How can i do?
Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I would use the `-amin` switch from the `find` command :

```
find <path> -name "*.mp3" -amin +10 -exec rm -f {} \;
```

From `man find` :

```
-amin n
              File was last accessed n minutes ago.
```

For testing or debugging purpose don't run the `rm` command, but `ls -l` instead :

```
find <path> -name "*.mp3" -amin +10 -exec ls -l {} \;
```

**Edit**

I just wanted to say a word about the `-delete` option : this option automatically turns on the `-depth` option.

Putting `-delete` will make `find` try to delete everything below the starting point specified. To avoid bad surprises i would explicitely specify the `-depth` option.

As i don't know the OP's folders/files tree i won't suggest him to use the `-delete` option alone. Seems a little unconscious to me.

At least i would suggest :

```
find <path> -maxdepth 1 -name "*.mp3" -amin +10 -delete
```

Comment: You don't need to use -exec, find has -delete too.

Comment: @lain As i mentioned in comment of another anwser, i usually use `-delete` with caution because it automatically turns on the `-depth` option ! So when using `-delete` i would explicitly specify `-depth`. So, in this specific case, i cannot see the gain of using `-delete`

Answer (score 3):

Assuming a reasonably up-to-date `find` command: `find /path/to/mp3/files -amin +10 -delete`.  I would, of course, run it without the '-delete' flag the first time through to make sure you're deleting what you think you're deleting.

From the `find` man page:

```
   TESTS
       Numeric arguments can be specified as

       +n     for greater than n,

       -n     for less than n,

       n      for exactly n.

       -amin n
              File was last accessed n minutes ago.
```

Comment: +1 for the `-delete`.

Comment: @Stone  Yep but warning with `-delete` : it automatically turns on the `-depth` option ! So you should explicitly specify `-depth` in order to avoid later surprises

Answer (score 2):

You can do this easily with `find`

```
find . -amin +10 -iname '*.mp3' -exec rm {} \;
```